# Puzzled about the way JAVA handles this workflow and reference situation. Can someone clarify?

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion, counter

I am quite uncertain about the way java flows through this simple code. I have managed to make it work, but I don't really understand why the problems that occur (see in code comments) unfold as they do.

More specifically:

- Why is there such a difference in functionality between "newCounter" and "counter++"?
- Why does counter++ work well for recursion while newCounter doesn't?
- Why does java catch only the first counter++ "else if" condition statement, but not the second one?
- And why does java catch both "else if" statements when I use newCounter instead of counter++
  I feel as though there might be some important principles into the way java is working that I am missing and should learn.

Any clarification about this or reference to key concepts/issues that are in play here would be very much appreciated.

Thanks, *CodeAt30*

```
System.Out.println(grow(1));

static int grow(int counter) {

    int newCounter = counter++;
    int limit = 8;

    if (newCounter < limit) {

        System.out.println("Counter: " + counter);
        System.out.println("New Counter: " + newCounter);   
        return counter * grow(counter++);                   // If I use newCounter here I loop out to failure as the number stays static (always under limit)
                                                            // counter++ does work though, providing a good <number>! calculation (7! or 6! etc.).      
    } else if (newCounter % 2 == 0) {                       
                                                            // If I use counter++ instead of newCounter in both "else if" statements though,
        System.out.println("even number");                  // java only catches the first one. An odd number is not caught,
        return 1;                                           // and final "else" statement is invoked. newCounter works well though.

    } else if (newCounter % 2 == 1) {

        System.out.println("odd number");
        return -1;

    } else {                                                // I do not want to reach this final else possibility.

        System.out.println("Got to else.....");
        return 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: You should read about the behavior of the post increment operator (counter++).

Comment: `int newCounter = counter++;` assigns the exact same value to `newCounter` as `int newCounter = counter;`

Comment: @Eran Thanks! Will look into this.

Comment: NB you can't have `*` in a method name. We would prefer examples to be code that compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in the understanding of `counter++`

The `++` after the variable is called the [postfix increment operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2). The relevant parts from the JLS are:

> the value 1 is added to the value of the variable and the sum is stored back into the variable.

and

> The value of the postfix increment expression is the value of the variable before the new value is stored

This means that `counter++` also assigns a new value to the variable `counter`. It's basically short for `counter = counter + 1`. This difference is that `counter++` also is an expression with a value. The tricky part is, that the value of that expression is the **old** value of `counter`. Run this small example for clarification:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int counter = 0;
    System.out.println(counter++);
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

There is also the [prefix increment operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1). Here the expression has the incremented value.

Comment: So the postfix increment expression is more of an "action" rather than a variable? As in it's not actually (x + 1) but rather an x = x+1 statement?

Comment: @CodeAt30 Correct. I just now realized that what you want is a little different from what I thought. I will edit my answer a little.

Comment: Alright I got it now. I was looking at the postfix incemerment expression totally awkward before. Now i get it. Played with my code and things are now making sense. Thanks! (at least I was right about this being kind of fundamentally important though haha).

Answer (score 0):

The logic of the code you have written here is pretty tough to understand, and that is because of the combination of `newCounter`, `counter` and your repeated calling of `counter++`.

```
 int newCounter = counter++;
```

... is equivalent to:

```
 int newCounter = counter;
 counter = counter + 1;
```

Therefore if you call `grow(5)`, after `newCounter` has been initialised:

```
 newCounter == 5
 counter == 6
```

Elsewhere you have:

```
 return counter * grow(counter++);
```

This is slightly difficult to reason about; it's equivalent to:

```
 int temp1 = counter;
 int temp2 = grow(counter);
 counter = counter + 1;
 counter = temp1 * temp2;
```

... so the end result would be the same with or without the `++`. Or to put it another way, the `++` here only makes it more confusing to understand.

Some languages, such as Python, don't have a `++` post-increment operator, because the designers believe it encourages confusing code. In my opinion, post-increment does have uses in clean code, but beginners should probably limit their use of it to very specific idioms (e.g. `for(int i=0; i<n< i++)`).

---

In your recursive code, you probably want `final int newCounter = counter + 1`.

Using `final` to tell the compiler that a variable's value is unchangeable in this scope, is a useful tool to make code easier to reason about.

Comment: thanks for this breakdown. Yes I was using the post-increment operator totally wrong. I understand it much better now. But will take your advice to minimize my usage of it at least for now.